# Android : Catch all http requests from an app and Edit header and Forward

Tags: android, header, try-catch, httprequest, handler

I want to Catch all request from a android app to the internet and Edit Header information. For example i want to add a Header field Host. Then forward to internet.
How this can be achieved.
My ideas for this:
1. Create an external app for this purpose and leave it to run in background to do task.
2. Edit that app to do that. i.e Embedding handler for an App. I don't know how to embed an handler to an android app. Like there are opera mini versions with the handler option in internet.

Please give me some suggestion for this.
Thank you  in advance. Because i know stack overflown with the solutions.

Comment: Do you need to catch all HTTP requests from one application or from your application where you have access to the source code? AFAIK your first idea is not applicable without root access due to security reasons.

Comment: From an External App. I don't have Access to Source code..

Comment: But without access to the code, how do you want to realize your second idea? However, without root access to the system AFAIK you won't have any chance to intercept and manipulate HTTP requests - it's permitted by the system (which makes totally sense ;)).

Comment: For example There is Opera mini Browser with External handler in web. The handler.apk used to modify the all HTTP requests from the opera mini. For Example [link](allgamesarena.blogspot.com/2013/03/download-opera-mini-next-7-handler.html) . How they did it.  OR else is it possible to catch all requests if i have root access, i mean super user.

Comment: We have to distinct. First of all your question refers to any HTTP request. Second, the posted link covers a "hacked" version of a browser, which is of course able to manipulate the HTTP requests of its users (which most basicly corresponds to your 2. idea but is not possible since you said you have no access to the source code). Anyway, are we talking about a serious use case here? Sounds a little bit dubious for me. Sorry, I am not aware of any approach for your scenarios... I had some extension of the HttpClient class in mind but that won't work for your scenarious. Sorry.

Comment: Is it possible to catch all requests if i have root access, i mean super user.. Please reply me.. If it is can, then i can move on.. else i have to think other idea. I just given example of opera mini. If they can modify HTTP requests, then why we can't. Please tell me if you have any other idea to catch..